# Need help identifying these vine berrys. Please!

Tags: identification, vines, berries

Had move in a new house had never seen these vines. They started growing out of nowhere. Grown so fast. Don't know if there edible or not. Need help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What part of the world are you located at? How tall is the vine?

Answer (score 3):

Booo! 
**Malabar Spinach it is!!**

**And yes, they are edible!!!**  
Those green leaves and that strong stem - you can eat them. Now about those black berries - they contain seeds. If you want young malabar spinach, you need to sow them. They can also be eaten when they are green, ie before they turn black. And the white ones on that stick are the flowers.